Why decaying of $\omega,\omega'$ imply the $a$ of $r^{n-1} \omega' +\frac{1}{2}r^n \omega =a$ equal to zero?
Assume $\omega(r)\rightarrow 0$ and $\omega'(r)\rightarrow 0$ when $r\rightarrow \infty$. And
$$
r^{n-1} \omega' +\frac{1}{2}r^n \omega =a
$$
Then, how to get $a=0$ ?
I have no idea. Maybe, a hint is enough for me. Thanks.

From Evans' Partial Differential Equations






Maybe a bit more context about the original problem is needed, since by reading your paragraph, it just looks like a regular physicist's argument: if you can safely assume that for some reasonable cause (unknown) the functions $\omega, \omega'$ will decay to zero as $r$ becomes arbitrarily larger, then the RHS must necessarily be zero as well. Maybe it's nothing too deep, again I suggest adding some further context.

Because the LHS tends to zero.

@Abezhiko, that’s what OP would like to demonstrate. $w(r)\to 0$ doesn’t imply $r^nw(r)$ does, etc.

Yes, indeed, but as is, there is not enough information in order to conclude that $a = 0$, that is why I suspect that the author assumes $\omega$ decays faster than $r^n$. It would have been safer to divide the equation by $r^n$ and then take the limit $r \mapsto \infty$, before concluding.

Let's be honest: Evan's argument is simply wrong --- if $n>0$, then $\lim_{r\to\infty}w,w'=0$ even if $a\neq 0$.

@Claudio  Thanks your advise. I have added the context, but seemly, there is not helpful information...

@Gonçalo: Can that limit behavior  be shown without explicitly solving the ODE?

@Aruralreader, it is straightfoward to obtain the asymptotic behavior of the solution as $r\to\infty$ without solving the ODE exactly. The result is $w(r)=a\left(\frac{2}{r^n}+\frac{4n}{r^{n+2}}+O!\left(\frac{1}{r^{n+4}}\right)\right)$.
